# Can't extrude plane consistently, sometimes just showing lines instead of full surface

Tags: extrude

I am trying to make a box layout (not folded yet) starting with a square plane. I was able to extrude the right side. But when I try to extrude the left side, only 2 lines are showing instead of the full face. I tried redoing multiple times, but there would be some areas that would not extrude a full surface. It would be just 2 lines sticking out without a surface. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I think you have produced "double vertices" at those locations that are not linked by an edge themselves. This could have been caused by accidentally extruding both vertex by a distance of zero at a earlier stage. If you select All in edit mode and then do "Merge by distance" (Alt+M), then those vertices at the shared location will merge to one vertex. From there on the face extrusion should behave as expected.

Comment: Maybe you have another underlying Problem: There must be an edge between both vertices to extrude a face from it. So if there is an vertex inbetween of the vertices you select for extrusion you need to select that also, otherwise it will not make a face. You can also use the "edge select mode" (icon in the top left i think) to select the edge instead of the vertices then you will be sure to extrude faces. If these Methods do not work maybe send a screenshot.